# Create DataItem in Dataview Sencha Touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I need create a dataview component with the following structure

[Structure](http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg338/scaled.php?server=338&filename=imgdj.png&res=landing)

I learned how to create simple text component, but this structure is more difficult.
I use this code, but is only the name field

```
Ext.define('DEMO.view.product.ListItem', {
extend: 'Ext.dataview.component.DataItem',
xtype: 'product-list-item',
config: {
    cls: 'product-list-item',
    dataMap: {
        getName: {
            setHtml: 'name'
        }
    },
    name: {
        cls: 'x-name',
        flex: 1
    },
    layout: {
        type: 'hbox',
        align: 'left'
    }
},
applyName: function(config){
    return Ext.factory(config, Ext.Component, this.getName());
},
updateName: function(newName, oldName) {
    if (newName) {
        this.add(newName);
    }

    if (oldName) {
        this.remove(oldName);
    }
}
```

});

Comment: as I see, if you're not going to create any `Ext.Component` inside your dataview, then you only need to use a list with scaled HTML template

Comment: But in list with scaled HTML template, i can't insert buttons or textfield components.
I need insert 2 buttons, the first to increase, the second to subtract the quantity.
How i do it?

Answer (score 1):

Just need to add the other components as the name. For example,

```js
Ext.define('App.view.UserItem', {
  extend: 'Ext.dataview.component.DataItem',
  xtype: 'useritem',
  config: {
    cls: 'user-item',
    firstName: { cls: 'first-name', flex: 1 },
    lastName: { cls: 'last-name', flex: 2 },
    layout: { type: 'hbox', align: 'center' },
    dataMap: {
      getFirstName: { setHtml: 'firstName' },
      getLastName: { setHtml: 'lastName' }
    }
  },

  applyFirstName: function(config) {
    return Ext.factory(config, Ext.Component, this.getFirstName());
  },

  updateFirstName: function(newFirstName, oldFirstName) {
    if(newFirstName) this.add(newFirstName);
    if(oldFirstName) this.remove(oldFirstName);
  },

  applyLastName: function(config) {
    return Ext.factory(config, Ext.Component, this.getLastName());
  },

  updateLastName: function(newLastName, oldLastName) {
    if(newLastName) this.add(newLastName);
    if(oldLastName) this.remove(oldLastName);
  }
});
```

For more detail, please visit http://www.sencha.com/blog/dive-into-dataview-with-sencha-touch-2-beta-2/

Comment: I use this example and i am developing the template using DataItem, but have a problem, you can see in this URL: [Demo Sencha](http://demosencha.260mb.org), following this steps:
1. Use any text in 'Usuario' and 'Contraseña', no problem
2. Click button 'Entrar'
3. Choose any item of the list, can be  'Alpina'
4. Use the search toolbar and write the word: 'Red'
5. Write any number in the textfield
6. Reset filter using the right button or erasing the word.

If all works good, the number that wrote will be in the first item('Poker'), the number was the item 'Redds', why not work?

Comment: I didn't find where you handle the change event of the quantity component. I think you should create one handler for it. In the handler you can update your record with the new quantity.

Comment: I don't understand very well, but i will try